# How to plot graph from file using Python, problem of the junction of lines

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm new to python and have a question. I have a file.csv file that contains two columns.

FILE.csv

```
0.0000    9.0655
0.0048    9.0640
0.0096    9.0592
0.0144    9.0510
0.0192    9.0392
0.0240    9.0233
0.0288    9.0028
0.0336    8.9770
0.0384    8.9451
0.0432    8.9063
0.0480    8.8595
0.0528    8.8039
0.0576    8.7385
0.0624    8.6626

0.0000   11.0013
0.0048   11.0018
0.0096   11.0032
0.0144   11.0057
0.0192   11.0091
0.0240   11.0134
0.0288   11.0186
0.0336   11.0247
0.0384   11.0317
0.0432   11.0394
0.0480   11.0478
0.0528   11.0569
0.0576   11.0666
0.0624   11.0767
0.0672   11.0873
```

I tried to plot the graph from FILE.csv
with xmgrace and Gnuplot, and the result is very convincing.

I have two lines in the graph, as shown in the two figure below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNEn0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRnfi.png)

On the other hand, if I use my python script, the **two lines are joined**
here is my script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as plt
#
with open('bb.gnu') as f:
    f=[x.strip() for x in f if x.strip()]
    data=[tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in f[2:]]
    BX1=[x[0] for x in data]
    BY1=[x[1] for x in data]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

plt.plot(BX1, BY1, 'k-', linewidth=2 ,label='Dos')
plt.plot()
plt.savefig("Fig.png", dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

And here's the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFXcU.png)

My question, does it exist a solution to plot graph with Python, without generating the junction between the two lines.
In order to find a similar result to Gnuplot and xmgrace.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A well-asked first question. Is `bb.gnu` the the csv file, or is it a different file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Yes exactly File.gnu = File.csv.
because I changed the format.

Comment: Did you delete the empty line?

Comment: Not on the contrary, the empty line is very important because I want to plot each part separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, matplotlib is only joining your two curves because you provide them as one set of data. This means that you need to call `plot` twice in order to generate two curves. I put your data in a file called `data.csv` and wrote the following piece of code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = numpy.genfromtxt('data.csv')
starts = numpy.asarray(data[:, 0] == 0).nonzero()[0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, num=0, figsize=(16, 8))
for i in range(starts.shape[0]):
    if i == starts.shape[0] - 1:
        ax.plot(data[starts[i]:, 0], data[starts[i]:, 1])
    else:
        ax.plot(data[starts[i]:starts[i + 1], 0],
                data[starts[i]:starts[i + 1], 1])
plt.show()
```

which generates this figure

[image]

What I do with `starts` is that I look for the rows in the first column of data which contain the value 0, which I consider to be the start of a new curve. The loop then generates a curve at each iteration. The `if` statement discerns between the last curve and the other ones. There is probably more elegant, but it works.

Also, do not import pylab, it is discouraged because of the unnecessary filling of the namespace.